# Converting .txt file directly into an array with custom delimiter

Tags: vba, excel, split

I am converting a .txt file directly into an array in excel VBA.  The default delimiter is a "," (comma) and I need to change it to "vblf".  I am having trouble figuring out how to do that with the code I have today.

Please help

```
    Const strFileName As String = [file]
    Dim CONFIGTXT(1 To 13000) As String
    Dim intFileNum As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer
    Dim strRecordData As String

    intFileNum = FreeFile
    intCount = 1
    Open strFileName For Input As #intFileNum
    Do Until EOF(intFileNum) Or intCount > 13000
        Input #intFileNum, strRecordData
        CONFIGTXT(intCount) = strRecordData
        intCount = intCount + 1

    Loop
    Close #intFileNum

    Range("Q2:Q" & UBound(CONFIGTXT) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CONFIGTXT)
```

Comment: You are currently trying to place an array of strings into a `String` variable.  That isn't going to work.  What shape did you want `CONFIGTXT` to be?  (At the end of your code you seem to be wanting to place it into a single column, so it sounds like you don't really want to `Split` the data at all.)

Comment: I accidentally posted my experimental code.  Please see the edited version.  I am not sure if split is the correct function to use.  What happens is the array is creating a new element each time it comes across a comma in the string rather than a new array element for each line in the .txt file

Comment: "What happens is the array is creating a new element each time it comes across a comma in the string rather than a new array element for each line in the .txt file" - Is that describing what you **want** to happen - i.e. you want a new entry in the array for each element, rather than each entry in the array representing one record?  So if you had two records, both saying `"abc/def"` (where `/` is actually a line feed) you want a `1 To 4` array created - you don't want a `1 To 2, 1 To 2` array?

Comment: I can't make sense of what you are suggesting in your comment.  I want a new entry in the array for each line in the .txt file...for example: line 1 in the .txt file contains "However, you are mistaken".  Currently the array brings the information as configtxt(1) = "However" and configtxt(2) = "you are mistaken"...What I would like to happen is configtxt(1) = "However, you are mistaken"

Comment: Well, your code as posted will do that - i.e. not split the records at all.  But your question is suggesting you want to split each record at the line feed characters - so I'm confused.

Comment: I've posted an answer based on what I **think** you are after, but I could be way off if you really mean what you say in the comments.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion.  Unfortunately, when I run the code as shown, the output range "Range("Q2:Q" & UBound(CONFIGTXT) + 1)" creates a new array element each time it comes across a line feed and again when it comes across a ",".  The first 100 lines of the .txt file do NOT contain any "," and, as expected, the first 100 elements of the array match the first 100 lines of the .txt file.  Line 101 in the .txt file is very long with multiple "," and therefore line 101 turns into the nex 5 elements of the array (ie element # 101, 102, 103, 104, 105)

Comment: This is line 101 & should be element 101..."IF FEATURE$[J_ORDERTYPE,J_OPTION] = "SLIDER" OR  (FEATURE$[J_ORDERTYPE,J_OPTION] = "REPL" AND NOT(POS(FEATURE$[J_REPLACEMNT,J_OPTION] = "HEADERLHP   RHP   ",6) ) )  THEN SELECTED = 1" but it turns into elements 101 through 105

Comment: OK, then my answer isn't going to do what you want.

Comment: Doh!! I stared at that code for ages and I finally saw the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Input #intFileNum, strRecordData
```

to

```
Line Input #intFileNum, strRecordData
```

`Input` is intended to read in data that is comma-delimited, one variable at a time.  For example, if you had data of

> 12345,789

and used the statement

```
Input #intFileNum var1, var2
```

then `var1` would be given the value `12345` and `var2` would be given the value `789`.

`Line Input` is intended to read a line at a time, delimited by the new line character (normally CR/LF).

---

Note:  If your data has information separated by line feeds, this will NOT separate those portions into separate entries in the array.  So if your data contains

> xxx/xxx/xxx

where the `/` is actually a line feed, that entire record will be placed into one cell in the final output.

Comment: AWESOME...finally.  Sometimes it's the simple things.

Comment: @Dave-Oh It must be about 10 to 15 years since I last had the need to use `Input` rather than `Line Input`, so I wasn't even thinking of that being an issue.  I was just thinking you had data with LFs in the middle of the record and were wanting to split the record as if each LF was a CR/LF.